# Create a link to a JSF page in a subfolder

Tags: jsf, url, path

I have a Java web app with the following structure:

```
- Project
     - Web Pages
          + WEB-INF
          + resources
          - administration
               systemsettings.xhtml
               userhandling.xhtml
          login.xhtml
          index.xhtml
          menubar.xhtml
          ...
     + Source Packages ...
```

I recently added the `administration` folder to the `Web Pages`, and I moved there the two `.xhtml` pages so I can write more specific URL pattern for my administrator authorization filter.

However, I don't know what is the path for the pages in the `administration` folder. While `<a href='index.xhtml'>` works, `<a href='administration/systemsettings.xhtml'>` doesn't, throws `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

**Update:**

The content of the systemsettings.xhtml was:

```
<h:body>
    <ui:insert name="header" >
        <ui:include src="menubar.xhtml" />
    </ui:insert>
    <div>Administration - System settings</div>
</h:body>
```

I forgot to update the path to the included page, after the refactor. This can be fixed, as @BalusC suggested, by changing the `<ui:include src="menubar.xhtml" />` to `<ui:include src="/menubar.xhtml" />`.

Comment: What do you mean with doesn't? Which error is shown?

Comment: Can you post whole stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a link does not start with a scheme like `http://`, then it's a relative link which is relative to the current request URI as you see in browser's address bar. If a relative link starts with `/`, then it's relative to the domain root in request URI. If a relative link does not start with `/` then it's relative to the currently opened folder in request URI.

If you can't tell about the currently opened folder for sure, then you need to make it a domain-relative link by explicitly prepending the context path as available by `#{request.contextPath}`.

```
<a href="#{request.contextPath}/administration/systemsettings.xhtml">settings</a>
```

An alternative is to just use JSF `<h:link>` component. It will automatically prepend the context path (and also automatically apply the JSF mapping!). The following `<h:link>` examples generate equivalent HTML.

```
<h:link value="settings" outcome="/administration/systemsettings.xhtml" />
<h:link value="settings" outcome="/administration/systemsettings" />
```